# Qual objeto tem melhor desempenho? SqlDataSource ou DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, desempenho, ado.net

Em questão de desempenho, velocidade, ou ate segurança, qual o melhor objeto para ser utilizado como um `DataSource`?

Exemplo, Estou criar um `DataSource`, para popular um `GridView`:

Por `SqlDataSource`:

```
this.sqlDataSource1.ConnectionName = "sql brayton max";
        this.sqlDataSource1.Name = "sqlDataSource1";
        columnExpression7.ColumnName = "id";
        table3.MetaSerializable = "0|0|125|100";
        table3.Name = "NotaFiscal.Cidades";
        columnExpression7.Table = table3;
        column7.Expression = columnExpression7;
        columnExpression8.ColumnName = "cd_uf";
        columnExpression8.Table = table3;
        column8.Expression = columnExpression8;
        columnExpression9.ColumnName = "ds_cidade";
        columnExpression9.Table = table3;
        column9.Expression = columnExpression9;
        selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column7);
        selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column8);
        selectQuery3.Columns.Add(column9);
        selectQuery3.Name = "NotaFiscal_Cidades";
        selectQuery3.Tables.Add(table3);
        this.sqlDataSource1.Queries.AddRange(new DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlQuery[] {
        selectQuery3});
        this.sqlDataSource1.ResultSchemaSerializable = resources.GetString("sqlDataSource1.ResultSchemaSerializable");
```

Por DataTable:

```
DataTable cli = new DataTable();

        string sqconn, _sql;

        sqconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql brayton max"].ConnectionString;

        _sql = @"SELECT id,cd_uf,ds_cidade FROM NotaFiscal.Cidades";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqconn);

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, con);

            con.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(cli);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: Apenas para sua informação: [DataTable: A Inimiga Oculta](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/datatable-a-inimiga-oculta/);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade depende. Eu diria que usar um `DataSource` (vai usar com `DataReader`, né?). O jeito de usar um ou outro vai determinar mais sobre a performance. `DataTable` é um objeto muito complexo e muita gente nem usa mais. Se usar errado qualquer um pode ser lento.

A única forma de saber é preparar testes de acordo com o que vai utilizar e verificar por conta própria de acordo com sua necessidade. Sempre é assim, se fizer diferença, porque é provável que nem faça. Problemas de performance se resolvem com técnicas específicas, dificilmente uma tecnologia fará tanta diferença (até faz, mas em casos extremos, quando todo o resto já foi feito).

Comment: Entendo. agora me surgiu uma duvida, hoje utilizo o DataTable, para popular alguns GridView, é melhor utilizar um DataReader com Dictionary?

Comment: Então, depende do que precisa. O `DataTable` pode ser mais fácil, mas ligeiramente mais lento. Faz diferença? Acho que não. Eu nunca o usei.

Comment: Perfeito, estou utilizando banco em nuvem, então todo segundo é questionável, vou realizar alguns testes obrigado.

Comment: Não estamos falando de segundo, talvez nem de milissegundo.

Comment: Certo, uma duvida, achei uma pagina na que descreve bem detalhado essa duvida, seria melhor somente deixar o link? ou fazer uma respostar colocando a fonte de dados?

Comment: Depende :P Não vi, pode por na pergunta, pode fazer uma resposta (desde que não seja só o *link*)

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel O DataReader tem uma função bem específica que é processar um grande volume de dados, somente à frente, somente leitura. Ele é rápido nesta função porque você pode começar a processar os registros antes mesmo de eles terem sido completamente retornados do banco, e você não precisa de uma RAM do tamanho da quantidade de registros porque eles podem ser descartados assim que processados. O DataTable tem uma função completamente distinta: trabalhar com todos os dados em memória, de maneira desconectada. Usar datareader p/ mandar todos os registros para um grid não faz sentido.

Answer (score 2):

A questão é desempenho/velocidade? Então a resposta é **NENHUM**.

Ambos são extremamente lentos e custosos para serem alocados, resolvidos, populados, lidos, etc. São objetos muito completos, porém com complexos metadados.

O melhor? Listas! Definitivamente.

Acesso seu banco de dados apenas com ADO.NET, usando apenas um `IDataReader`. Popule sua lista e finalize o *DataReader* e passe sua lista para o `GridView.DataSource`.

Escrevi um artigo sobre isso: [DataTable - A Inimiga Oculta](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/datatable-a-inimiga-oculta/). Título careta, mas o conteúdo é muito relevante. Tudo explicando [porquê deve-se evitar usar DataTable](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/datatable-a-inimiga-oculta/).

Comment: Thiago obrigado, vou ler seu artigo.